# Override global hotkey Alt-F2 in gnome when my program is in foreground

Tags: linux, x11

My problem is similar to this: http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=14451

Gnome seems to call `XGrabKey()` for Alt-F2, but it's also a hotkey in my program. How to make my program receive this event instead of Gnome shell, when it's in foreground?

If I call `XGrabKey()`, it will return `BadAccess`. If I call `XGrabKeyboard()`, then my program will supress all other global hotkeys.

Comment: Even if possible, I'd advice against this. Alt+F2 is a really common hotkey used not only in Gnome, but many other desktop environments to run a command/program. Surely there must be others that fit the task better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. You do not receive the event. The root window receives the keypress and is owned by the window manager. The window manager then delegates the keypress. Global shortcuts take precedence.

An evil hack could be to alter Gnome's global shortcuts while the program is running. The users will burn your house down for this.

Another alternative is, as you mentioned to grab the keyboard. Then you receive the events instead of the root window. You could pull the evil hack of passing keypresses that you are not interested in (other global shortcuts) to the root window via the XTest extension. The users will burn your house down for this.

The users will probably be quite happy though if you change your shortcut.

Comment: Is it possible to handle such keypress event by the root window only in case if it's not processed by topmost application yet?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Possible in the point of whom's view? The window manager? The topmost application?